# PHP/Javascript/Jquery - Dynamic Website Diagram

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, diagram

I want to have an application that displays all of my website's external links and outputs a diagram. Like for example www.example.com/articles/some-title.html is linked to my homepage.

```
Home
 - www.example.com/some-text  
 - www.another-site.com/my-title
 - www.example.com/articles/some-title.html Products
Products
 - www.buy-now.com/product-reviews/231/098989
 - www.sales.com/432/title-page.html Categories
 - www.ezinearticles.com/blah-blah-blah
```

Something like [SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/demo/), but not on CSS.

I have setup a table on my DB so this will be dynamic and more links to come. I'm using CakePHP in working on this. Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: not on css. On what you want it then?

Comment: How do you intend to style the resulting html? If it was me I would make a sitemaps controller. Then use something like this, http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/07/21/how-to-list-all-controllers/ to generate a sitemap as I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to retrieve the results from the database and you can use [**jQuery's treeView**](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) to display them.

Also, [**raphaël.js**](http://raphaeljs.com/) might be of interest, especially its [**diagram**](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) plugin, its fully customizable and should be something to check out.

Comment: Hmmm.. this might do it. But I'll take a look at others suggestions.

Comment: Of course, I added some more links so you can get a sense of what else is out there.

Answer (score 2):

You can see slickmap, is a css implementation for site diagrams

http://astuteo.com/slickmap/

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to parse the contents of an entire web site (HTML, JS, etc...), and create an array that contains all of your links, as well as the pages that they can be found on. If that is correct, this code will get the job done:

```
<?php

$path = "./path_to_your_files/";

$result = array();

if ( $handle = opendir($path) ) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

            $contents = file_get_contents($path . $file);

            preg_match_all("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+"."(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/", $contents, $parts);

            foreach ( $parts[1] as $link ) {

                $result[$file][] = $link;

            }

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

print_r($result);

?>
```